How to add rest api images so we can add it in our GitHub to refer later
I created one project and at the end to test I took REST APIs screenshot. I want to know what's best way to keep all those images at one place.
Either in Readme or somewhere?
In folder or in Readme file.
Thank you already. If you have link please share so I can refer.

Please find below the details The REST API screenshots organized and easily accessible on GitHub are to be stored in a folder within your project repository and then referenced in the README.md file.
README file code is written here locally or direct to GitHub repo
## REST API Testing Screenshots

Here are the screenshots taken while testing the REST APIs:

### Endpoint: /api/getData
![Get Data API](./images/get-data-api.png)

### Endpoint: /api/postData
![Post Data API](./images/post-data-api.png)

Add the folder and updated README.md to your GitHub repository:
git add images/ README.md
git commit -m "Add API screenshots and update README" //this is a comment according to modify
git push origin main/master (Branch)

GitHub README files in the official GitHub Markdown Guide.

Thank you that is very useful information I was looking forward to.
